# Python 3 interpreter prints length to standard input for every write

Tags: python, anaconda

There are a few questions about this kind of behaviour:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout.write("aaaa")
aaaa4
>>>
```

I understand what's going on there. What I don't understand is what's happening in my case: regardless of which file I open, whenever I use its `.write` method, the length of the data is written to the console/to `stdout`.

```
>>> with open("garbage.file", "wb") as f:
...     for x in range(4):
...         f.write(b"xyz")
...
3
3
3
3
>>> with open("garbage.file", "rb") as f:
...     assert f.read() == b"xyzxyzxyzxyz"
...
>>>
```

However, this behaviour does *not* occur when I let `python` run it as a script:

```
D:\>type CON > test.py
with open("garbage.file", "wb") as f:
    f.write(b"xyz")

^Z

D:\>python test.py

D:\>type garbage.file
xyz
D:\>
```

This happens with any fresh Python 3.5 interpreter used on a Windows command prompt (either the "normal" `cmd` or the "Anaconda Prompt").

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>>
```

I've never seen this behaviour before, and it doesn't look like it's supposed to happen either. What could be the cause? How can I resolve it?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This is a more general question. I was led here because my interactive Python was printing 8, which I recognized to be the string length. If anything, this is a more general question. If I had searched using "8", I wouldn't have found this useful question and answer. However, the OP in this post mentioned length. Also, @Kieran, your answer here is better, because it not only explains the problem better (more completely) by noting the difference between the interactive console (interpreter) and a Python script.

Comment: Also, @Kieran, there is an additional question in this post ("How can I resolve it?"), which I would like to answer. I cannot do so, because this post is closed to answers due to being tagged a duplicate. I'll add an answer to the other post, while adding a link here. By the way, the fix is to assign the return value to a variable on the interpreter, e.g. use `catch_ret_val = f.write(b'xyz')`

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a duplicate of this question: [sys.stdout.write in python3 adds 11 at end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32576576/sys-stdout-write-in-python3-adds-11-at-end-of-string)

Which explains that `.write()` returns the number of characters written after it's been written to the file. Which explains why you see it in the interpreter but not the file you've created.

Edit: Examples showing the interpreter show return values and the python executable ignore them.

```
>>> def show(string):
...     print(string)
...     return(len(string))
... 
>>> show('foobar')
foobar
6
```

Now if I create a file with the exact same contents I get:

```
$ python show.py 
foobar
```

This is because the `python` executable doesn't show returned values whereas the interpreter does.

Comment: I fail to see how this is a duplicate. I'm not writing an expression on the Python prompt, but a statement. Moreover, this would not explain how it prints the value of the expression statement *every time* it is executed. Surely, this is abnormal behaviour.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was quick to call this a duplicate. But I think that linked thread explains what your problem is.

Running your code in the interpreter will always show the return values of any function you run, whereas running it through `python` executable will not show you the return values. 

I don't believe this is abnormal behaviour.

Comment: I've edited my original answer to add a bit of clarification, does that help anymore? @Rhymoid

Comment: @Rhymoid The interactive interpreter prints the value of an unassigned expression, unless it evaluates to `None`.

Comment: @PM2Ring ... you're right O_o I wonder how I've never had this before.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. This is a more general question. I was led here because my interactive Python was printing `8`, which I recognized to be the string length. If anything, this is a more general question. If I had searched using "8", I wouldn't have found this useful question and answer. However, because the OP in _this_ post mentioned length. Also, @Kieran, your answer here is better, because it not only explains the problem better (more completely) by noting the difference between the interactive console (interpreter) and a Python script.